# Prodigy + Spacy to train dataset

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, prodigy

I would like an example of using Prodigy to train a dataset (text file with some named entities). This file would be in Portuguese. The idea would be to train a model with Prodigy to make notes for the recognition of named entities (I'm not sure how Prodigy works). And then use Spacy + Python to load a trained model and apply it to new files to recognize named entities.

Thank you

Comment: I think your question is both too broad and asks for a recommendation on tutorial. It probably won't receive an answer here as the idea is to help with more focused questions on specific problems. E.g. "Why isn't your spaCy model loaded for training by Prodigy?" For more details, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This video on training an NER model with Prodigy/spaCy may be interesting to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59BKHO_xBPA. The code and data can be found here: https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/master/ner-food-ingredients